# Decentraland/cli Error: (Critical error: error initializing rendering) occurs when I use IP to connect the server

Tags: typescript, windows, metamask, decentraland, decentraland-ecs

I encountered a problem that is giving me a headache.

I run the following command in Window OS:

```
dcl start --web3
```

and access the browser URL with:   http://10.6.88.XX:8080.

I receive the following error: 'Critical error: error initializing rendering.'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdgH2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM3Uh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP6nW.png)

The strange thing is,
I can run the server properly with the URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080.

For more information, I have tried to do the exact same thing in Mac OS environment, no problem occur,      and I can access with my local IP address or using 127.0.0.1

Have any of you experienced this issue before, and do you know how to solve it?